# AWS SNS processing multiple message in one Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a process that in a very quick period of time is publishing many SNS messages that would be processed by Lambda. However, Lambda is processing it one at the time. Is it a way to apply something similar to SQS long pooling?

I have code:

```
exports.saveLog = async (event) => {
  console.log('Event : ', event.Records.length);

  event.Records.forEach(record => {
    const sql = record.Sns.Message;
...
```

I would like to Lambda receive a set of messages if they are published in a short period of time - Is it possible?

Comment: Can you define short period of time? The only change you can make is adjust the `Batch size` option of the Lambda event.

Comment: up to 1 second - I do not see option `batch size` with Lambda nor SNS

Comment: If you look at the triggers on your Lambda, you should be able to update the option there

Comment: such option is available if a trigger is SQS not SNS

Comment: Ah was reading the `Is it a way to apply something similar to SQS long pooling?` part

Comment: Are your lambdas not scaling out to process them in parallel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon SNS is essentially just a pub-sub system that allows you to publish a single message that gets distributed to one or more subscribed endpoints.

To process multiple messages in a single downstream process, you can add an Amazon SQS Queue that picks up the messages from the SNS topic and a Lambda function that retrieves the messages in batches from the queue.

Comment: How about if the batch contains 10 messages and 7th message processing fauls and throws an exception. How would lamda let sqs know to delete only 6messages which are processed so far?

Comment: @ManishRawat you need to configure you lambda with batchItemFailures: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting

Comment: @RRC this is nice to know.. i guess the only edge case is if somebody unplug the machine while it’s processing the messages (say 4 out of 10 processed) in this situation when next time batch processing starts it will probably process from the beginning. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ManishRawat yes that is correct